# DataGridView C# добавление изображения, имя которого берется из dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

Доброе утро, столкнулся с проблемой следующего характера. Есть база данных ms sql которую подключаю через источники данных в visual studio, таблица содержит данные о фильме один из атрибутов которой является имя файла изображения (posterData). К форме добавляю datagridview и устанавливаю, как источник данных таблицу, добавил новый столбец типа DataGridViewImageColumn и с помощью данного цикла добавил Image:

```
private void SelectedFilmForm_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "movieDBDataSet.vMovies". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
        this.vMoviesTableAdapter.Fill(this.movieDBDataSet.vMovies);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Image poster = new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + @"\Resources\Images\" + (string)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["posterData"].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PosterImage"].Value = poster;

        }
    }
```

Программа запускается и изображения видны, но при клике на заголовки колонок для сортировки изображения исчезают. С чем это может быть связано и как это можно исправить?
DataGridView до сортировки по Году выхода:
[image: DataGridView до сортировки по Году выхода]
DataGridView после сортировки по Году выхода:
[image: DataGridView после сортировки по Году выхода]

Comment: Так картинки загружаются при загрузке формы, а при изменении DataGridView ничего ведь не происходит, а по-идее должно.